# How To Remove a Slider from Responsive Design

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, slider

I'm a small business owner that has (up until now) managed a successful website.

However, with the pending Google Mobilegeddon, my website for some reason does not pass the Google Mobile Friendly test (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/). I believe this is due to the slider as when I disable the slider plugin and remove it. The website passes it.

The website is built in WordPress using Catalyst/Dynamik as the child theme. The plugin I use for the slider is Soliloquy. I have tried so many different sliders that at this point I would like to just take out the slider for the responsive/mobile version only.

I have this as the code in the responsive panel:

```
#header-wrap {background:none !important;}
.logo-image #header-wrap #header {width:100%;text-align:center;}
.logo-image #header #header-left {width:200px;background:url('images/air-conditioning-brisbane.png') no-repeat scroll center top transparent;margin:0 auto !important;}
.logo-image #header-left, .logo-image #header-left #title, .logo-image #header-left #title a {width:200px;}
#callus {margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;}
.slider-wrapper, #soliloquy {display:none;}
```

I think it has something to do with the last line.

Can I please request any assistance to help remove the slider from the mobile/responsive version.

Your help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I'd need to see your html also - can we view the site live/have you a preview?

Comment: Sure AnnieMac. The url is rapidairconditioningbrisbane.com.au

Answer (score 0):

Some pieces are out of context here, but if you have access to editing the CSS then this shouldn't be a problem. I'm also uncertain of your skill-level so I'll assume you have close to zero coding experience.

First you need to find the element's selector. You can do this by using Chrome or Firefox and right clicking the slider and use Inspect Element. Find the root element and note it's selector. Look at the "class" and "id" attributes if they exist. Preferably grab the id. The CSS file should then look like this:

```
/* up to wide mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* using the ID of the element */
    #my-slider {
        display: none;
    }

    /* using the class of the element */
    .my-slider {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If it's still not hidden on mobile it could be because of precedence, you could increase precedence by adding more parents to the CSS selector and/or adding the !important flag.

```
body .my-slider {
    display: none !important;
}
```

If you're using the Jetpack plugin you can also paste the style into the Custom CSS Stylesheet, or you can also paste the style into the style.css file in /wp-content/themes/catalyst-theme/style.css.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use media queries to hide this. The class for div containing the slideshow seems to be .soliloquy-container so add the following to the bottom of your stylesheet

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .soliloquy-container {
    display: none;
 }
}
```

That should resolve the problem for you - let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Thanks AnnieMac and @dgilmore. While it does remove the slider from the responsive version, it still appears when Google crawls it in the test.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?url=http%3A%2F%2Frapidairconditioningbrisbane.com.au%2F

It's very weird. I don't know why Google renders a different responsive/mobile design as to me when it runs the mobile friendly test?

Comment: I'm away from my computer right now to review this 'from google's perspective' but I'll have a look in a few hours if no one else gets to it- sorry for the delay

Comment: Hey, I just checked this now (sorry for the wait) and it is saying that is site is now mobile friendly? Perhaps initially google was still seeing a cached version of the site? https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?url=http%3A%2F%2Frapidairconditioningbrisbane.com.au%2F

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it's perfectly acceptable to simply hide the slider for mobiles using a css media query like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .your-slider-container {
    display: none;
 }
}
```

**It's worth noting that the images will still be loaded even if they're not displayed.**

If you're serving up large 1100 to 1920 pixel wide desktop images, it would take much longer loading on a `3g` mobile network, and be unfair on the users wasting their bandwidth on something they wont see.

**I would recommend the following solution:**

**1)** set your slider to hidden by default:

`.your-slider-container {display: none;}`

**2)** Swap the `src` attribute of all images (`img`) in your slider to `data-src` so that images aren't requested on page load; then use the following Javascript to call the images if the screen is larger than your desired size.

```
if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {

    var slider = $('.your-slider-container');

    slider.find('img').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
    }); //load images

    slider.sliderPluginName(slider_options); //call slider
    slider.show();

}
```